# WC3 Webite logging format

Tags: iis, logging

I have an IIS webserver that is crashing occasionally. It always works just fine after restarting the AppPool. I have logging configured for the website in a standard W3C format. Looking through the logs for useful information is like sifting through vomit for a tasty treat. Are there any good tools out there for making these logs more readable? User Friendly? Useful?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out Smarter Stats from http://www.smartertools.com/smarterstats/web-analytics-seo-software.aspx

The free edition is really nice.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently looking into this.

Comment: Annnnnddddd.... *drum roll* YOU my friend are the winner. This tool is awesome.

Comment: Great find. The free edition seems to do everything I want. I can't believe it's free!

Answer (score 1):

[Nihuo web log analyzer](http://www.loganalyzer.net) is very simple, easy to configure and very good in analyzing iis and apache access log files. The reports generated by this tool are also very good.